# Unordered lists in SO Careers 'personal statement' section might need some extra margins

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

Currently, when placing an unordered list in the 'personal statement' section, the list item markers will be positioned left relative to the containing block.

Maybe it is just me, but this looks *ugly*.

Some extra margin on the left side will 'solve' this 'problem'.

[image: Unordered lists uglyness]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this only happens if the list is the last item in your personal statement.  It was caused by having a little too much CSS.  This has been cleaned up and will go out with the next push.